# Find the continuous least squares trig polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, least-squares

Find the continuous least squares trigonometric polynomial $S_{2}(x)$

for $f(x) = 2x - 1$ on $[-\pi , \pi]$

I know $S_{2}(x) = \frac{a_{0}}{2} + a_{1}cos(x) + a_{2}cos(x) + b_{1}sin(x)$

but for solving for the $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$, I don't think I am getting the correct numbers.

$a_{0} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(2x-1)cos(0x)dx = -2$

$a_{1} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(2x-1)cos(1x)dx = 3.6*10^{-14}$

$a_{2} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(2x-1)cos(2x)dx = -2.2*10^{-13}$

$b_{1} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(2x-1)sin(1x)dx = 4$

Which would make it $S_{2}(x) = -1 + 3.6*10^{-14}cos(x) + -2.2*10^{-13}cos(x) + 4sin(x)$

That doesn't seem right to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those tiny values are calculated numerically, they are almost certainly *exactly* zero. This means that your first approximation is 
$4\sin(x)-1$.

Get some additional terms,
plot the results,
and see how close that is to
$2x-1$.

You should also be able
to *analytically* evaluate
the integrals
for $a_n$ and $b_n$
once you have
$a_1$ and $b_1$.